# Showing compactness of an operator

Tags: compactness, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces, calculus-of-variations, compact-operators

Let $g: \Omega\times C^2(\Omega)\to\mathbb{R}, (x,u)\mapsto u(x)|u(x)|^{p-2}$, where $\Omega$ is a smooth, bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $2<p<\frac{2n}{n-2}$. 
I found a proof, that $K:H_0^1(\Omega)\to H^{-1}(\Omega), K(u) = g(\cdot, u)$ is compact, but I have some problems understanding it.

First of all it is said that $u\mapsto g(\cdot, u)$ maps bounded sets in $L^p(\Omega)$ into bounded sets in $L^{p/p-1}(\Omega) \subset H^{-1}(\Omega)$. (1)

Then, because of this and since Rellich-Kondrakov gives that $H_0^1(\Omega)$ embeds into $L^p(\Omega)$ compactly (2), the map $K:H_0^1(\Omega)\to H^{-1}(\Omega), K(u) = g(\cdot, u)$  is compact.

I can't follow that argumentation.

What we want to show is that $K$ maps bounded sets into relative compact sets.

So first of all we know by Rellich-Kondrakov, that a bounded set $M$ in $H_0^1(\Omega)$ is relative compact in $L^p(\Omega)$. Why does (1) then gives me relative compactness of the image of $M$ in $L^{p/p-1}(\Omega)$?

Can someone explain me the steps in between?

Comment: It seems they are saying because the maps $L^p \to L^{p/(p-1)},L^{p/(p-1)}\to H^{-1}$ are continuous and bounded and the map $H_0^1 \to L^p$ is compact, the composition sends a bounded set of $H_0^1$ to a compact set of $L^p $ to a compact set of $L^{p/(p-1)}$ to a compact set of $H^{-1}$

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have still one question. Let $\tilde K: L^p(\Omega) \to L^{p/p-1}(\Omega),  u\mapsto g(\cdot,  u)$. Then let $M\subseteq H^1_0(\Omega)$ be a bounded set. Furthermore let $i: H^1_0\to L^p$ be the compact embedding between $H^1_0$ and $L^p$ and $j: L^{p/p-1}\to H^-1$ the continuous embedding between $L^{p/p-1}$ and $H^-1$.Then $K(M) = j(\tilde K(i(M)))$ and as $i(M)$ is relative compact and $j$ and $\tilde K$ are continuous $K(M)$ is relative compact. Is that correct? Why do we show boundedness of $\tilde K$?

Comment: Showing the boundedness for me just would make sense, if we would have linearity of $\tilde K$. But this is not the case here.